# variable modified in a function and returned modified when it should not

Tags: python

I am using the following program:

```
def coordsRelToPoint(origin,point):

    result = (int(origin[0]) - int(point[0]) , int(origin[1]) - int(point[1]))

    return result

def initCoordsRelToStartBattle(calibration):
    print ('FUNCTION BEGIN')
    print ('orig: %s' % str(calibration['center']))
    print ('')
    new_calibration = {}
    new_calibration = calibration

    print ('orig: %s' % str(calibration['center']))
    print ('')

    new_calibration['center'] = coordsRelToPoint((774,454),calibration['center'])

    print ('orig: %s' % str(calibration['center']))
    print ('')
    print ('new: %s' % str(new_calibration['center']))
    print ('')
    print ('FUNCTION END')           
    return new_calibration

def main():
    calibration = {}
    calibration['center'] = (156,20)
    initCoordsRelToStartBattle(calibration)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It is printing the following on screen:

```
FUNCTION BEGIN
orig: (156, 20)

orig: (156, 20)

orig: (618, 434)

new: (618, 434)

FUNCTION END
```

What I don't understand is why my original variable is modified when calling a function when it should not because it is used in another function.

I should never see the line orig: (618, 434) because this means that my variable calibration has been modified even if it was not returned from the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you assign an existing dictionary to a new variable, actually the new variable points to the same object. You can check basically the address of the object by using [`id`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) function. In the example, `id(calibration)` and `id(new_calibration)` and you will see they have the same address. That's the reason why if the new dictionary is modified also the original dictionary is modified.

In order to have an actual new copy, namely , you can use [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) package, and use `deepcopy` function. The line that you should change is the initialization of `new_calibration`, namely:

```
new_calibration = copy.deepcopy(calibration)
```

and this results in preserving the original variable.

Note that in the code of the question, a shallow copy works too, as [`tuple`](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Tuples) are the element of the dictionaries, which is an immutable object. The difference between shallow and deep copy is basically that the first one creates a new compound object and when possible add references found in the copied object, while the latter recursively create new objects. In the question, if in the dictionary each element was a list of two elements instead of a tuple, then in order to modify just one single value of a list while preserving the list in the original dictionary, a deep copy would be necessary.
For more information about the difference between shallow and deep copy, refer to the [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) documentation.

Comment: It's not a copy at all, not even a shallow one; it's simply another reference to the *same* object.

Comment: @DanielRoseman you are right, I fixed the explanation of the error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have the following statement in your code:

```
new_calibration = calibration
```

This means if you change new_calibration, you're also changing calibration, which is why the changes are reflected in the print statement.

Answer (score 0):

`new_calibration = calibration` just means that `new_calibration` refers to the same object that `calibration` refers to.  If you want to make a copy, use the `dict.copy()` method:

```
new_calibration = calibration.copy()
```

Also, `new_calibration = {}` is useless if all you are going to do is redefine `new_calibration`.